# Javascript function alert is undefined in Visual Studio simulator

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio

I am developing an App for Windows 8.1 and I have Visual Studio installed. I am developing an app using Javascript in the Windows RT API.

```
alert("hello");
```

When I use the very common function above, the simulator halts and returns error:

> 'alert' is undefined

So, I guess I cannot use that function. But still want to log some stuff. Is there any logging feature I can use as possible alternative to `alert`? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

```
console.log("Hello");
```

Works as for common browsers.